# Inner Join on the Same Table using Where to Filter

Tags: mysql, sql

Thank you for helping me out, I'm still learning SQL. I've got a master table called JEDI that I'm trying to get specific information on using Inner JOIN and Where conditions. Specifically, I'm looking to get a count of JEDI and their rank who visited specific planet between certain dates.

And then I want to use an Inner JOIN on the same table to filter and only show me the results from JEDI who had more than 1 padawan in that specific planet. I think the second where condition is throwing me off. I've pasted my code that I've used and an example data table

My results should just be 2,Master for Obi Wan as his the only one who meets the criteria

```
SELECT COUNT(jedi.jedi_id),jedi.rank_id
FROM jedi
WHERE jedi.date >='2022-01-01' AND jedi.date <='2022-06-31' AND jedi.planet='Tatoine'
INNER JOIN jedi ON jedi.jedi_id WHERE COUNT(jedi.padawan)>=2
GROUP BY jedi.rank_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use having to replace this ***INNER JOIN jedi ON jedi.jedi_id WHERE COUNT(jedi.padawan)>=2***

Comment: Thanks @learning I did think about that option - will `having` look at the time window in the original WHERE statement or will it overrule it?

Comment: the time you mentioned is the date? or? If is the date, it will do filtration as well. Just remove the line, and add having at the last line, having count(....)>1

Answer (score 1):

First you need to group the column and use `HAVING COUNT` to count duplicate values.

```
SELECT COUNT(jedi.jedi_id),jedi.rank_id
FROM jedi
WHERE jedi.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-06-31' 
                                     AND jedi.planet='Tatoine'
GROUP BY jedi.jedi_id, jedi.rank_id
HAVING COUNT(jedi.jedi_id) > 1
```

Note: This will only work if every `jedi_id` has a unique value of `jedi.padawan`. This query would work in those scenario.

However you can improve the query by adding another condition that counts unique `jedi.padawan` so that repeated values of `jedi.padawan` on every `jedi.jedi_id` will not be included

```
SELECT COUNT(jedi.jedi_id),jedi.rank_id
FROM jedi
WHERE jedi.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-06-31' 
                                     AND jedi.planet='Tatoine'
GROUP BY jedi.jedi_id, jedi.rank_id
HAVING COUNT(jedi.jedi_id) > 1 AND
       COUNT (DISTINCT jedi.padawan) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Its_Me - where though would the filter to capture only 2 or more padawans come in though?

Comment: From the jedi_id, assuming that every jedi_id it has a unique value of jedi.padawan. This query would work in those scenario.